# How do I suppress the bloat of useless information when using the DUMP command while using grunt via 'pig -x local'?

Tags: dump, apache-pig, gruntjs, verbosity

I'm working with PigLatin, using grunt, and every time I 'dump' stuffs, my console gets clobbered with blah blah, blah non-info, is there a way to surpress all that?

```
grunt> A = LOAD 'testingData' USING PigStorage(':'); dump A;
```

*2013-05-06 19:42:04,146 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig features used in the script: UNKNOWN

2013-05-06 19:42:04,147 [main] INFO
  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MRCompiler - File concatenation threshold: 100 optimistic? false
...

...

 **--- another like 50 lines of useless context clobbering junk here...   till ---**
...

...

org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Success!*

**now my like 4 lines of info looking for:**

```
(daemon,*,1,1,System Services,/var/root,/usr/bin/false)
(uucp,*,,,/var/spool/uucp,/usr/sbin/uucico)
(taskgated,*,13,13,Task Gate Daemon,/var/empty,/usr/bin/false)
(networkd,*,24,24,Network Services,/var/empty,/usr/bin/false)
(installassistant,*,25,25,/usr/bin/false)

grunt>
```

---> obviously if it errors, fine lotsa info helpful, but not when it basically works great.

Comment: I tried the above , it doesn't work...
However this link works http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16627748/pig-batch-mode-how-to-set-logging-level-to-hide-info-log-messages

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the log4j properties.
For example:

```
$PIG_HOME/conf/pig.properties :
enable:
# log4jconf=./conf/log4j.properties

rename: log4j.properties.template -> log4j.properties

log4j.properties :
set info to error:
log4j.logger.org.apache.pig=info, A
```

You may also set the Hadoop related logging level as well:

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop = error, A
```

Comment: There seems to be a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-3275) in Pig 0.12.0 which causes this to fail.

Comment: @Xaero182 I think that 0.12.0 uses logback instead of log4j.Try adding this JAVA OPT : -Dlogback.configurationFile=/path/to/your/logback.xml file.

Answer (score 6):

An easy way to do this seems to be to redirect standard error as below.
But it will suppress all **`errors`**.

```
pig -x local 2> /dev/null
```

Also found that if you remove or rename your hadoop install directory to basically make it inaccessible to pig then all those INFO messages go away.
  Changing logging levels in hadoop didn't help, just so that you know.

Comment: This, frankly, is the only one that answers the question directly and provides a simple solution. Creating and editing a log4j.properties file doesn't really cut it for me.

Comment: It is the best way for me

Answer (score 3):

When you start pig, pass it a log4j.properties file with `pig -4 <filename>`.

In my case there was a log4j.properties in the `conf` directory and setting the level of the logger named `org.apache.pig` to `ERROR` is sufficient to make the logger less verbose.

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.pig=ERROR, A
```

Answer (score 0):

pig has debug log level one need to set that in `pig.properties` file,

```
# Logging level. debug=OFF|ERROR|WARN|INFO|DEBUG (default: INFO)
#
# debug=INFO
```

The reason one get large logs on console, e.g. change it to ERROR

Comment: Do we need to restart Unix after this change? it is not working for me. I updated it but it is not working.