# Pig: Hadoop jobs Fail

Tags: java, csv, hadoop, apache-pig

I have a pig script that queries data from a csv file.

The script has been tested locally with small and large .csv files.

In Small Cluster:
It starts with processing the scripts, and fails after completing 40% of the call

The error is just, 
    `Failed to read data from "path to file"`

What I infer is that, The script could read the file, but there is some connection drop, a message lose

But I get the above mentioned error only.

Comment: If any answer have solved your problem, click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not :/

Comment: Can you provide more information, like logs or exceptions?

Comment: export HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS="-Xmx128m ${HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS}" would allocate 128 MB(Yran default 200) for every task(map or reduce) in a container, but the heapsize which is as a default 1 GB can be changed by setting an environement variable YARN_HEAPSIZE = Memory in MBs

Answer (score 2):

An answer for the General Problem would be changing the errors levels in the Configuration Files, adding these two lines to mapred-site.xml

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop = error,A 
log4j.logger.org.apache.pig= error,A
```

In my case, it aas an OutOfMemory Exception

Answer (score 1):

Check your logs, increase the verbosity level if needed, but probably you're facing and Out of Mem error.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16414020/1006863) on how to change Pig logging.

To change the memory in Hadoop change the `hadoop-env.sh` file as you can see documented [here](https://github.com/hanborq/hadoop/blob/master/example-confs/conf.secure/hadoop-env.sh)

```
# The following applies to multiple commands (fs, dfs, fsck, distcp etc)
export HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS="-Xmx128m ${HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS}"
```

For Apache PIG you have this in the [header of pig bash file](https://github.com/apache/pig/blob/trunk/bin/pig):

```
# PIG_HEAPSIZE The maximum amount of heap to use, in MB.
# Default is 1000.
```

So you can use `export` or set it in your `.bashrc` file

```
$ export PIG_HEAPSIZE=4096MB
```

Comment: I have just followed it, adding two lines in the log4j.properties file, wich are 
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop = error, A
log4j.logger.org.apache.pig= error, A

would I get more information about what is going wrong ? sorry every script takes 1 hour to get an error(this one is running too), wanted to be sure,
about the out of Memory, how can I set this in Hadoop?
Thnx very much

Comment: Indeed it is an Out Of Memory Exception, how can I raise to Limit now ?

Comment: @MahmoudHabiballah check my edit on how to raise the memory limits for Hadoop and Pig.