# Hadoop error log jvm sqoop

Tags: linux, hadoop, sqoop

My mistake - after 6-8 hours of running programs on Java i get this log  hs_err_pid6662.log

and this

```
  [testuser@apus ~]$ sh /home/progr/work/import.sh
  /usr/bin/hadoop: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
  /usr/bin/hadoop: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
  /usr/bin/hadoop: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
  /usr/bin/hadoop: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
  /usr/bin/hadoop: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Programs run every five minutes and try to import/export from oracle

How to fix this?

```
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Cannot create GC thread. Out of system resources.
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
# This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
#
#  Out of Memory Error (gcTaskThread.cpp:48), pid=6662, 
tid=0x00007f429a675700
#
---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007f4294019000):  JavaThread "Unknown thread" 
[_thread_in_vm, id=6696, stack(0x00007f429a575000,0x00007f429a676000)]

Stack: [0x00007f429a575000,0x00007f429a676000],  sp=0x00007f429a674550,  
free space=1021k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native 
code)


VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xmx1000m -Dhadoop.log.dir=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.1-
1.cdh5.11.1.p0.4/lib/hadoop/logs -Dhadoop.log.file=hadoop.log -
Dhadoop.home.dir=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.1-
1.cdh5.11.1.p0.4/lib/hadoop -Dhadoop.id.str= -
Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,console -


Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_102


# JRE version:  (8.0_102-b14) (build )
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.102-b14 mixed mode linux-
amd64 compressed oops)
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core 
dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again

Memory: 4k page, physical 24591972k(6051016k free), swap 12369916k(11359436k 
free)
```

I am running programs like sqoop-import,sqoop-export on Java every 5 minutes.
example:

```
#!/bin/bash

hadoop jar /home/progr/import_sqoop/oracle.jar.
```

CDH version 5.11.1

java version jdk1.8.0_102

OS:Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.9 (Santiago)

Mem free:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
 Mem:      24591972   20080336    4511636     132036     334456    2825792
 -/+ buffers/cache:   16920088    7671884
Swap:     12369916    1008664   11361252
```

Host Memory Usage
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dpd8.png)

Comment: Add more details to your question...

Comment: Which kind of details?

Comment: My mistake , it is there....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum heap memory is (by default) limited to 1GB. You need to increase this

> JRE version:  (8.0_102-b14) (build )
>   jvm_args: **-Xmx1000m** -Dhadoop.log.dir=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.1-
>   1.cdh5.11.1.p0.4/lib/hadoop/logs -Dhadoop.log.file=hadoop.log -
>   Dhadoop.home.dir=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.1-
>   1.cdh5.11.1.p0.4/lib/hadoop -Dhadoop.id.str= -
>   Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,console -

Try the following for to increase this to 2048MB (or higher if required).

```
export HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS="-Xmx2048m ${HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS}"
```

Reference:
[Pig: Hadoop jobs Fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27524788/pig-hadoop-jobs-fail)
https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hadoop-mapreduce-user/201104.mbox/%3C5FFFF0E4-B3BA-420A-ADE3-B422A66E8B11@yahoo-inc.com%3E

Comment: In which file i can set this?

Comment: In /etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.yarn/hadoop-env.sh ?